# Crashed when load libtesseract302d.dll?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, tesseract

I'm using Tesseract library in Visual Studio 203. But the application crashed with this Exception:

> {System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for
>   'LParking.Base.Global' threw an exception. --->
>
> System.IO.FileLoadException:  Could not load file or assembly
>   'CPPWrapper.dll' or one of its dependencies.  The application has
>   failed to start because its side-by-side configuration is incorrect.
>
> Please see the application event log or use the command-line
>   sxstrace.exe tool for more detail.
>
> (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x800736B1)  at LParking.Base.Global..cctor()  --- End of inner
>   exception stack trace ---  at LParking.MainWindow..ctor() in e:\TIN
>   HOC\Learning\Chuong Tring Dao
>   Tao\Working\Main_Code\LParking\branches\LParking\LParking\MainWindow.xaml.cs:line
>   33}
>            EVENT LOG DETAIL Activation context generation failed for 
>           "E:\TIN HOC\Learning\Chuong Tring Dao Tao\Working\Main_Code\LParking\branches\LParking\Bin\x86\Debug\libtesseract302d.dll".
>   Dependent Assembly
>   Microsoft.VC90.DebugCRT,processorArchitecture="x86",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",type="win32",version="9.0.21022.8"
>   could not be found.
>
> Please use sxstrace.exe for detailed diagnosis.

Note that: When I build the application in Release mode (use libtesseract302.dll) then It worked fine. But when build the application in Debug mode (libtesseract302d.dll), it crashed as I mentioned above!

Comment: "Dependent Assembly Microsoft.VC90.DebugCRT could not be found" ?

Answer (score 2):

The last  line of the trace indicates that the VC2008 (VC90) library is missing.  Get them from http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=29

Comment: It can not solve my problem, but I fixed it by using libtesseract302.dll for both Debug and Release mode. Thank You!